# Create an Id col for a run in kdb/q

Tags: kdb

```
a       b            c
458     newcol1      s
902     new2         e
458     newcol1      e
902     new2         s
458    newcol1       s
902    new2          e
458    newcol1       e
902    new2          s
```

example table above

what I would like to do is add an id column to the above table

- a is unique but not to a run
- a run starts when column c =s
- a run ends when column c = e
- a run is during when column c = d
- if a start and end is defined the next id of column a should have a new run number
- a run is complete with a start then and end so if an id in col starts with a end this will have a different id
  so for example this is what I would like the end table to look like:

```
a       b            c     ID
458     newcol1      s     1-458
902     new2         e     2-902
458     newcol       d     1-458
458     newcol1      e     1-458
902     new2         s     3-902
458    newcol1       s     4-458
902    new2          e     3-902
458    newcol1       e     4-458
902    new2          s     5-902
```

I’m unsure of how to go about this id column would someone be able to help to help me?

I was thinking off

- if statement to check if a run had started if it did apply a Id
- keep checking for the same number in col a to check if it ends once it does apply the same id
  But not sure how to implement this thanks
- tried joining and using each and scan over

Answer (score 2):

Solution is a little messy but the core logic is something like:

```
q)t:([]a:458 902@010010101b;b:`newcol1`new2@010010101b;c:`s`e`d`e`s`s`e`e`s)
q)update ID:@'[;a]{@[x;y;:;(x@y;max[x]+1)not[y in key x]|`s=z]}\[{x!x}1#0;a;c] from t
a   b       c ID
----------------
458 newcol1 s 1
902 new2    e 2
458 newcol1 d 1
458 newcol1 e 1
902 new2    s 3
458 newcol1 s 4
902 new2    e 3
458 newcol1 e 4
902 new2    s 5
```

If you want to embellish the result with the "a" column and hyphens

```
q)update ID:{`$"-"sv string[x,y]}'[;a]@'[;a]{@[x;y;:;(x@y;max[x]+1)not[y in key x]|`s=z]}\[{x!x}1#0;a;c] from t
a   b       c ID
-------------------
458 newcol1 s 1-458
902 new2    e 2-902
458 newcol1 d 1-458
458 newcol1 e 1-458
902 new2    s 3-902
458 newcol1 s 4-458
902 new2    e 3-902
458 newcol1 e 4-458
902 new2    s 5-902
```

Answer (score 1):

The core of the problem is to calculate the run number. No iteration is necessary; and lookup is likely to be faster than iteration. Below, the table columns are vectors `a`, `b`, and `c`.

A new run number is required where column `c` is `s`, or a new value appears in `a`. (Below, `fui` is an ancient APL algorithm.)

```
q)fui:{(x?x)=til count x}  / flag unique items
q)show s:(c=`s)or fui a    / flag new runs
110011001b
q)show r:s*sums s          / run numbers
1 2 0 0 3 4 0 0 5i
```

To fill in the zeros we look back to the run number for the previous occurrence of the same value of `a`. For that we need a map of where the runs start for each value.

```
q)show d:group[a]inter\:s
458| 0 5
902| 1 4 8
```

The missing run numbers:

```
q)r j@'-1+sum each ns>j:d a ns:where not s
1 1 3 4i
q)@[r;ns;:;] r j@'-1+sum each ns>j:d a ns
1 2 1 1 3 4 3 4 5i
```

Putting it all together:

```
t:([]a:458 902@010010101b;b:`newcol1`new2@010010101b;c:`s`e`d`e`s`s`e`e`s)

fui:{(x?x)=til count x}                    /flag unique items
r:s*sums s:fui[t`a]or`s=t`c                /new run #s
d:group[a]except\:ns:where not s           /map run starts
@[`r;ns;:;] r j@'-1+sum each ns>j:d a ns;  /look up current run
t[`ID]:`$"-"sv'string r,'t`a               /format
```

You could squeeze the logic into qSQL queries, but as you need variable `d` anyway, it’s arguably simpler and clearer to calculate vector `r` and format it back into the table.